# Layout Animation does not work on Android even with UIManager experimental settings

Tags: android, react-native, animation, uimanager, layout-animation

I've been trying to implement `LayoutAnimation` to animate the insertion and deletion of items from scrollView. I've added the below code for the same.

```
import { LayoutAnimation, NativeModules } from 'react-native';

// Animation setup for android
const { UIManager } = NativeModules;
UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
```

to set the layout animation

```
// Animate the add or removal of shortlisted Rail
  useEffect(
    () => LayoutAnimation.configureNext({ ...LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut, duration: 500 }),
    [shortlistItems],
  );
```

Can anyone help me with this? why is this not working in android?

I've been following this documentation : https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation

**`NB : This works great in iOS without any issue.`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Reanimated to overcome this. Now the application works really great.

REF 1 : https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/layout_animations/

REF 2 : https://youtu.be/6UXfS6FI674

Answer (score 0):

I found the code mentioned here works better on Android:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13207

```
 LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
      duration: 300,
      create: {
        type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
        property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
      },
      update: { type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut },
    });
```

Apparently there is some issue with the delete animation